# Stripe Checkout Subscription with subscription fee is failing

Tags: stripe-payments

I can't figure out why my request is failing, I'm trying to create a checkout session with subscription mode and collecting a fee. This is the error message i get returned from Stripe.

```
{message: Can only apply a subscription application_fee_percent when the Checkout Session is made on behalf of another account (using an OAuth key or the Stripe-Account header).}
```

I am NOT using my main platform accountID, I have created a new connected user using express. And I am passing the new users connected accountID to my server for creating a session.

Here is my server code:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price: 'price_Xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      subscription_data: {
        application_fee_percent: 10,
        transfer_data: {
          destination: accountId,
        },
      },
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: 'http://localhost:49430/stripesub?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:49430/stripesubcanceled',
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      'sessionId': session.id
    });
```

The subscription product or `line_items -> price` is a product I have created with my main platform account, not the connected account created with express.

My mission is to create a service where businesses can register with express, choose a subscription tier, and have their users/members sign up to their platform by paying the subscription and gain access.

Comment: That seems like a bug in Stripe(the exact same kind of call but not using Checkout and using the Subscriptions API works), so I'd write to their support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time talking to Stripe support i found out that this is wrong:

```
subscription_data: {
        application_fee_percent: 10,
        transfer_data: {
          destination: accountId,
        },
      },
```

and it should look like this:

```
subscription_data: {
        transfer_data: {
          amount_percent: 90,
          destination: accountId,
        },
      },
```

Comment: This is technically different though since it doesn't create explicit ApplicationFee objects and has a slightly different funds flow, it's the difference between https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#application-fee and https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#transfer-amount , so there's still a legitimate bug where both approaches should be supported by Stripe.